# How to pass a variable from an installer to another one in install4j

Tags: install4j

I have a first installer that I launch using this command:

```
sudo ./installer.sh -q -VDO_NOT_LAUNCH_SERVICE=true
```

This installer can get and use the variable `DO_NOT_LAUNCH_SERVICE`.

At the end of install, this installer launches another one using the `Run executable or batch file` with arguments:

```
return new String[] {"-q", "-Dinstall4j.keepLog=true", "-VDO_NOT_LAUNCH_SERVICE=true"};
```

but it seems that the second installer doesn't care of this parameter :(

Is there any solution please?

Thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, passing an array of `String` to Run executable or batch file Action.

The good method: Arguments (one string per line)

```
-q
-Dinstall4j.keepLog=true
-VDO_NOT_LAUNCH_SERVICE={$installer:DO_NOT_LAUNCH_SERVICE}
```

Comment: So to make this clear for future visitors, the problem was that you put a script in the "Arguments" property of the "Run executable or batch file action" instead of the arguments?

Comment: Exactly, that was the problem